# keras ResNet50 input_shape

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, resnet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuAo2.png)

Code:

```
resnet_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

pretrained_model= tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                   input_shape=(48,48,1),
                   pooling='avg',classes=7,
                   weights='imagenet')
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable=False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

I want to use Resnet50 for 1 channel but I am getting the error. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, ImageNet weights are only available for 3 channel images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.